# Radix Sort C++ problem ex of sorted: 10,2,2,4,5,7

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to create a binSort/Radix sort array to sort 1mil to 10 mil binary numbers.
so far I got this and the problem :
I see is that for example I have 2, 10,9,2,4,6,2,2,8,10
the sorted number would come to be
10,10,2,2,2,2,4,6,8,9
I don't know where it went wrong.

```
int getMax(int arr[], int size)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
}
void binSort(int arr[], int size)
{
    int max = getMax(arr, size);
    for (int pas = 1; max / pas > 0; pas *= 10)
    {
        countBin(arr, size, pas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using standard containers and algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I notice is that you are returning early from the getMax:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }
    return max; // this should be out of the loop.
}
```

Comment: There should be a compiler warning right about there as well. It's possible for the program to never enter the loop and thus never return a value. Syntactically correct, but most often the wrong thing to do, so a compiler may point it out. When the compiler raises an issue with the code, even if it compiles, it's worth taking a look. Odds are really good the compiler's right and the program will fail at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you edited your initial code, but I would like to give some feedback on your programming. When using C++ you should learn to use everything it has to offer. The standard defines a library which offers containers and functions commonly used.
Not doing so leads to the issues to encounter.
A mistake is for instance

```
int bin[10] = { 0 };
```

this only sets the first element of the array to 0... the rest is left uninitialized.

As you are storing a variable length (1 to 10 million) array on the heap, you should start using the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

And you should also start using the [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).
e.g. this copy

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr2[i];
}
```

Could be realized using [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n)

```
std::copy_n(arr, size, arr2);
```

But in the case you are using a `std::vector`, you could just copy by a simple assignment.

```
vec = vec2;
```

Or even, if you think about it, it doesn't make sense to copy the contents, if `arr2` (or it's `vector` equivalent i call `vec2`) is deleted directly afterwards. You can just have the pointer (`arr`) point to the contents of `arr2` and delete the old data of `arr`. In case of a `vector`, we can do a move-assignment

```
vec = std::move(vec2);
```

The the `getMax` function can completely be replaced by the algorithm [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

```
int const max = *std::max_element(cbegin(vec), cend(vec));
```

In C++20 you can even use [`std::ranges::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/max)

```
int const max = std::ranges::max(vec);
```

Another important thing you must consider is that a division operation is expensive. Thus if you do the operation `(arr[i] / pas) % 10` you have 2 divisions (`%10` is also a division). And you do that 3 times for up to 10 million elements per loop.
However, you can reduce the computation cost be realizing how computers work: they store values in binary format. Now you probably chose '10' because we learn mathematics using the decimal system. But dividing by 10 is difficult for the binary computer.

What *is* simple for binary computing is dividing by a power of 2, because you can realize this with a simple bitshift. E.g. `x/2 = x>>1` and `x/8=x>>3`. Similarly, you should then replace the remainder (`%10`) with a bit masking: `x%2 = x&1` and `x%8 = x&7`.

In the end your whole code can be reduced to something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

constexpr auto shiftStep = 4;
constexpr auto nrOfBins = 1 << shiftStep;
constexpr auto bitMask = nrOfBins - 1;

void binSort(std::vector<int> &vec) {
    int const max = *std::max_element(cbegin(vec), cend(vec));
    for (int shift = 0; (max >> shift) > 0; shift += shiftStep) {
        std::array<int, nrOfBins> bins; bins.fill(0); // C++ std::array instead of C-style array
        for (auto el : vec) bins[(el >> shift) & bitMask]++; // range based for loop, shifts and mask instead of division
        std::transform(cbegin(bins), cend(bins), begin(bins),
            [prev = 0](int el) mutable {return prev += el; }); // mutable lambda
        std::vector<int> vec2(vec.size());
        std::for_each(crbegin(vec), crend(vec), // reverse iterator
            [&](int el) { vec2[--bins[(el >> shift) & bitMask]] = el; }); // pre-increment instead of two operations
        vec = std::move(vec2); // move assignment
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = { 2, 10,9,2,4,6,2,2,8,10 };

    binSort(vec);

    for (int el : vec) std::cout << el << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```